# if the cursor over on the image in the sense marquee not stop. it is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please refer to [this website here](http://www.kepranprojects.com/keprandemo). I have used marquee in best seller product. when I will go to over the image in the sense quick view pop will come. if am over on the image means it will stop. but over on the quick view image in the sense it doesn't stop. how I can stop this. please help me it's killing my time.the following code for use this marquee.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(function() {

        $(".items").simplyScroll({autoMode: 'bounce'});

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: You are give some answer. but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The Quickshop ID is over the images, including the div items. Just add the same functionality to the quickshop link

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".items, #em_quickshop_handler").simplyScroll({autoMode: 'bounce'});

    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: $(".items, #em_quickshop_handler").simplyScroll({autoMode: 'bounce'});

Comment: Thank you, changed it. I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: i use this code. but it's not working. after add this code the quick view lable not come.

Comment: #em_quickshop_handler is dynamically added to the class by jQuery..And this autoscroll function uses another jQuery so how do i use this id.i used above code but its not working..please help me out

Comment: I've made a small edit. You can try it this way. Now the code won't execute till the rest is loaded. This might solve your problem.